# How to override cmsplugin-filer templates in Django CMS

Tags: django-cms, django-filer

I have tried to override the default templates in **cmsplugin-filer** but I had no luck so far. Anytime we use the **Link** plugin within the CMS there is an option where we can select the template but it always says **Default**. How can I add templates to that list?

I have tried adding my own template to the templates folder, but it didn't work:

```
/templates/cmsplugin_filer_link/link.html
```

The documentation says nothing about templating, does somebody know how to achieve this?

Comment: Hello, are you sure the link plugin comes from cmsplugin-filer? There's another app which has a Link plugin called djangocms-link.

Comment: You are right @Paulo, I have just tried adding ``/templates/djangocms_link/default/link.html `` and it worked, thanks!